# VBA Webscrape Loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel, web-scraping

I have a code below that will scrape all the info from a page for whatever one ticker I put into A2. I use a vlookup separately to put a statistic in a cell next to it, then copy and paste it into another area so not to mess with the vlookup (kind of innificient, I know, but not the question.)

I have a second stock ticker in A3 I want to do the same thing for...but I don't know how to properly loop the code for A3. The code currently just does it twice for A2. (This problem probably has to do with the my_page line of code sticking to A2? )

Anyways, I just want the code to spit out something. copy/paste what I want.
Then go to line two, spit out the webpage. copy/paste in the row under the first. and so on.

Any advice on how to loop by row?

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("A2:A3")

    For Each row In rng
        For Each cell In row.Cells

            Range("F4").Select
            my_Page = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & Range("A2").Value
            Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
            With IE
                .Visible = True
                .Navigate my_Page
                Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            End With

            Application.EnableEvents = False
            IE.ExecWB 17, 0
            Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            IE.ExecWB 12, 2
            Sheets("Sheet1").PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
            Range("F4").Select

            IE.Quit
            Application.EnableEvents = True

            Range("A2:B2").Select
            Range("B2").Activate
            Selection.Copy
            Range("H2").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        Next cell
    Next row

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, your error is in this line:

```
my_Page = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & Range("A2").Value
```

Try this:

```
my_Page = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & Range("A" & rng.row).Value
```

Also, you can eliminate the `For each cell in row.cells` ... `Next`, because you never reference `cell`

You'll also have to change these lines:

```
Range("A2:B2").Select
Range("B2").Activate
Selection.Copy
Range("H2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone_
, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

to this:

```
Range("B" & rng.row).Copy
Range("H" & rng.row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone_
, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Range("H" & rng.row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Notes:

- eliminating the `.select` reduces the number of lines of code & greatly increases the readability.
- eliminating all uses of `Active*` is strongly recommended to avoid confusion. It's easy enough to declare and assign variables for workbooks, worksheets & cells to give them meaningful, clear & non-confusing names. Much better than trying to figure out what `ActiveSheet` is really pointing to 12 lines of code later.

**UPDATE**

I hate working with ranges like that, they hurt my head.  Here's a variation with a simple `For...Next` loop based on the range

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As integer
'Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:A3")

For i = rng.row to rng.rows.count
    Range("F4").Select
    my_Page = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=" & Range("A" & i).Value
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate my_Page
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    IE.ExecWB 17, 0
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    IE.ExecWB 12, 2
    'NOTE: This will ALWAYS paste into F4 - is that what you want?
    Sheets("Sheet1").PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", link:=False,
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

    IE.Quit
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Range("B"&i).Copy
    Range("H" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, _
          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    'I believe this is redundant after the line above...
    Range("H" & i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
          SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
Next 

End Sub
```

Comment: Trying it out. If AAPL is in the first stock cell A2, it still is navigating to AAPL's page twice instead of moving down to the ticker under. Not sure what is wrong at this point. It'll look up the price, put it in B2 and paste in H2. Look up A2 again, put the price into B2/ paste into H2 again. Maybe something else needed with the Next row line at the end?

Comment: I think that `For i = range.row to range.rows.count` should be `For i = rng.Row to rng.Rows.Count`